# Expandable listview Child item Click not working

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

In My expandable list view first child item has two buttons.button1 and button2.in other child list item has check box and text.these check boxes are default disabled
in first time user expand the child list and after press button1 i want to enable all check boxes in particular group

As this point i can only enable first child list item checkbox.how can enable all check boxes by clicking button on the 1st child item.

Expandable list adapter

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ExpandableListGroup> groups;

public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExpandableListGroup> groups) {
    this.context = context;
    this.groups = groups;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<ExpandableListChild> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ExpandableListChild child = (ExpandableListChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.btn_start_inspection = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_inspection);
        holder.btn_complete_inspection = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_complete_inspection);
        holder.cbx_complete_inspection = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_sub_task);
        holder.txt_activity_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sub_task_title);

        holder.txt_activity_name.setText(child.getName().toString());

        //button for enable checkboxes
        holder.btn_start_inspection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.btn_complete_inspection.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                holder.itemEnabled = true;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        //enable check boxes
        if(holder.itemEnabled == true){
            holder.cbx_complete_inspection.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            holder.cbx_complete_inspection.setEnabled(false);
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<ExpandableListChild> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return chList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ExpandableListGroup group = (ExpandableListGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_company_name);
    tv.setText(group.getName());

    TextView tvAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_company_address);
    tvAddress.setText(group.getAddressLevel());

    iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_expand);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    iv.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.exp_fold));
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    iv.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.exp_min));

}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    Button btn_complete_inspection;
    Button btn_start_inspection;
    CheckBox cbx_complete_inspection;
    TextView txt_activity_name;
    boolean itemEnabled = false;
}

}
```

listchildItem.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lnrChild"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnr_task"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/btn_start_inspection"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_cornerexpandable_list_child"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Start Inspection"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            ></Button>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_complete_inspection"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rounded_cornerexpandable_list_child_gray"
            android:text="Complete Inspection"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            ></Button>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnr_active_sub_task"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_complete_inspection">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnr_sub_task"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check_sub_task"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:gravity="center"></CheckBox>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/textHolder"
                android:layout_width="0.0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sub_task_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="exx"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0.0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sub_task_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

What I see is that after click button on 1st list item only 1st check box in the 1st child item is enabled, the other list item check boxes are not. What I want is that  checkboxes in the child item rows are enabled. (extra lines added from comments)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your question is? What do you want to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: as this point after click button on 1st list item only enable 1st check box in the 1st child item.but other list item check boxes not enable. @Christine but i want to enable all checkboxes in the child item rows.